# In angular, the attribute value does not work in an input field

Tags: html, css, angularjs, input

I'm just normally using an input tag and I wanted to insert some text already with the value tag but it just won't work, this is my code line:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" value="14" type="number" ng-model="textLetterGrootte">
```

As far as I can see I'm not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you use AngularJs ngModel directive, remember that the value of
>   **value attribute does not bind on ngModel field**.You have to init it by yourself and the best way to do it,is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aY8rE/55/)

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="number" ng-model="textLetterGrootte"  ng-init="textLetterGrootte=14">
```

Comment: Please explain why this work in order to help other people. What does `ng-init` and why with just the `value` attr it's not enough.

Comment: How do I use ng-init when I want to display text instead of numbers ?
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="textKleur">

Comment: <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="textKleur" ng-init="textKleur='SOMETEXT'"/>

Comment: @SVK Sorry, ng-init="textKleur="SOMETEXT"" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use single quotation .ng-init="textKleur='SOMETEXT' " @Goldenowner

Comment: Jup, thanks single quotation works ! You're awesome +rep @SVK

Comment: @Goldenowner.. :) (thumbsup)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have accepted the answer, let me put it so you will understood it in depth. The official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) says ng-init will take any expression. So yes, you can do what you want above as long as the associated scope defines a function called init() or assigning the initial value directly.

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope.

Thus, as you can simply initialize your variables when the controller is created. So there's really no need to use ng-init at all. 
For example:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.textLetterGrootte = 14;
  };
  // runs once per controller instantiation
  $scope.init();
}]);
```